# Send data from Adapter to broadcast receiver and receive in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, broadcastreceiver

**send data from to receiver and get in fragment**

I want to receive data which I have passed from Adapter but it not even getting called

**receiver class(the class is in Fragement)**

```
 public class DataReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        try {
            if (intent != null) {
                Category category = (Category) intent.getSerializableExtra("category");
                Log.e("data", category.getName());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("catch", e.toString());

        }

    }
}
```

I have created receiver in below fragment and register and unregister receiver here.

**AddServiceFragment class(receiver is in it)**

```
  @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        bindViews();
        dataReceiver = new DataReceiver();
        filter = new IntentFilter("action");


    }
@Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        getActivity().registerReceiver(dataReceiver, filter);
    }


    public void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        getActivity().unregisterReceiver(dataReceiver);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();

        getActivity().registerReceiver(dataReceiver, filter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        getActivity().unregisterReceiver(dataReceiver);

    }
```

I am using below code to send data to receiver

**adapter code**

```
 holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent in = new Intent(context, AddServiceFragment.DataReceiver.class);
            in.setAction("action");
            in.putExtra("category", category);
            context.sendBroadcast(in);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using wrong way. Please check below sample code.

**Code in fragment class:**

```
@Override
    public void onResume() {
        getActivity().registerReceiver(mReceiverLocation, new IntentFilter("data_action"));
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        getActivity().unregisterReceiver(mReceiverLocation);
        super.onPause();
    }

    private BroadcastReceiver mReceiverLocation = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            try {
                Category category = (Category) intent.getSerializableExtra("category");
                Log.e("data", category.getName());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
```

**Call from adapter class:**

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent in = new Intent("data_action");
                in.putExtra("category", category);
                context.sendBroadcast(in);
            }
        });
```

Comment: i just have to change in adapter class    no not working at all.. no logcat

Comment: @unknown yes, because your receiver class is already in fragment.

Comment: no not working at all.. no logcat printed  and one thing  i have created receiver in another fragment and  another fragment contains adapter  so receiver and adapter is inot in same fragment class......  (example : A fragmnet contains receiver and B fragmnet contains adapter

Comment: @unknown Are both fragments visible in ui?

Comment: @unknown then it won't because new fragment visible on screen and your previous fragment's on pause will call and your receiver is going unregister

Comment: yes visible ....Listen Again @Nischal.. Fragment A has one button .user click on button user been redirected to another fragment all category being listed there ..user selected one category (here i send data to brodcast ok)after selecting  one category user comes back Fragment A.. here he will see his selection in a view(lets say in imageview)....  now got it?

Comment: @NiranjPatel i commented code on onPause still didnt work and i remove unregister from onDestory it throws error so which flow i have to pursue ?

Comment: @unknown this is not proper way.

Comment: @NiranjPatel so can u suggest me a proper way? and i don't want to use EventBus Lib

Comment: I think @NiranjPatel is correct. When you navigate to categoryList fragment your previous fragment's onPause() will be called so you won't be able to receive broadcasts.

Comment: @Nischal yes i got it but any other way ?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this:
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html
You can communicate between your fragments through the host activity.

> Often you will want one Fragment to communicate with another, for example to change the content based on a user event. All Fragment-to-Fragment communication is done through the associated Activity. Two Fragments should never communicate directly.